# Analytical expression for the value where maxima of the function occurs

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to find the expression of $\theta$ for which the following equation is maximized.

$$f(\theta)=\{a-b~cos\theta-c~sin\theta\}^{-\eta}+\{a-b~cos\theta+c~sin\theta\}^{-\eta}$$

Here, $a$,$b$,$c$ and $\eta$ are constants (real numbers).

I have tried to differentiate the equation with respect to $\theta$ and equate to zero, but that leads to an expression from which I could not subject $\theta$.

What is the procedure for maximizing this sort of equation? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By symmetry the derivative is $0$ when $\sin(\theta) = 0$.  At least for some range of parameters that may give the solution.  Any other critical points are unlikely to have closed-form expressions.

Comment: Yes, by simulating the equation in MATLAB I can see that for some range of parameters the function is maximized(global minima) at $sin\theta=0$ or $\theta=n\pi$, and for some range of parameters the function has a local minima at $theta=n\pi$.
Now, I have to figure out the analytical expression of  the range of parameters for which this function has a maxima at $\theta=n\pi$.
Is it possible ?

Comment: You can check that when $\sin \theta = 0$ and $\cos \theta = 1$ the second derivative is $2 (a-b)^{-2-\eta} \eta (c^2 (1+\eta) + b^2 - a b)$, so when that is negative you have at least a local maximum at $\theta$.  Similarly when $\sin\theta = 0$ and $\cos\theta = -1$ the second derivative is $2(a+b)^{-2-\eta} \eta (c^2 (1+\eta) + a b + b^2)$.